# Array dentro de otro por id

Tags: javascript

Tengo los siguientes arrays:

```
//data
    [
    {
      "idAgen":36,
      "asesor":"ARCANGEL",
      "idRegion":3,
      "region":"U",
      "idZona":3,
      "zona":"ARIO",
      "campos":291
      },
      {
      "idAgen":67,
      "asesor":"MIGUEL",
      "idRegion":3,
      "region":"U",
      "idZona":3,
      "zona":"ARIO",
      "campos":888
      },
      {
      "idAgen":90,
      "asesor":"JOSE",
      "idRegion":3,
      "region":"U",
      "idZona":3,
      "zona":"ARIO",
      "campos":291
      }
     ]

//pronostico
    [
      {
      "idAgen": 36, 
      "pronostico": 410693
      },
      {
      "idAgen": 36, 
      "pronostico": 8347
      },
      {
      "idAgen": 67, 
      "pronostico": 9877
      },
      {
      "idAgen": 67, 
      "pronostico": 9000
      },
      {
      "idAgen": 67, 
      "pronostico": 5363
      },
      {
      "idAgen": 90, 
      "pronostico": 896
      }
    ]
```

Y lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente (para cada objeto de data):

```
    [
    {
      "idAgen":36,
      "asesor":"ARCANGEL",
      "idRegion":3,
      "region":"U",
      "idZona":3,
      "zona":"ARIO",
      "campos":291,
      "pronostico":[
        {
        "pronostico": 410693  
        },
        {
        "pronostico": 8347 
        }  
        ]
      }
     ]
```

He intentado esto pero no funciona,agrega los valores por separado,
asi:

```
    //data
    [
    {
      "idAgen":36,
      "asesor":"ARCANGEL",
      "idRegion":3,
      "region":"U",
      "idZona":3,
      "zona":"ARIO",
      "campos":291
      },
      { 
      "pronostico": 410693
      },
      { 
      "pronostico": 8347
      }
    ]
```

Primero itero ambos arrays, empiezo con pronostico ya que es mas grande que data, despues itero data, donde la propiedad idAgen sea igual em ambos agregar los valores de pronostico con push.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < pronostico.length; i++) 
         {
          for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            if (pronostico[i]['idAgen'] == data[j]['idAgen'])
            {
              data.push({pronostico :pronostico[i]['pronostico']});  
            }
          }        
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Hola que se supone que estas intentando??? puedes dar una descripción de que hace tu código y cual es el error?

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent ya añadi un ejemplo de lo que hace

Comment: si pero explica que hace tu ejemplo; que fallo tiene y que esperas que haga ... pegar codigo solo no ayuda mucho XD

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent espero sea as claro ahora

Comment: creo que tus arrays parecen objetos... o me equivoco??? .. parecen cadenas de string json ...

Comment: si son JSON @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent

Comment: una pregunta cuantos elementos tendra el primer objeto json, data puedes generar un ejemplo con datos para 3 asesor??

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent ya añadí mas información, puede tener N elementos

Comment: no puedes tener mas de un indice en el mismo nivel con el mismo nombre ...

Comment: la estructura que planteas donde hay 2 pronosticos en el mismo nivel no se va a poder se van a sobre escribir ...

Comment: lo que no entiendo es por que en uno se llama proyección y en el otro pronostico ... puede decidir que vas a usar para cada nodo?

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent y como podria ser para que no se sobreescriban?

Comment: tenia tu respuesta y se me ha ido del editor, dame unos minutos XD

Comment: ya esta la respuesta

Comment: te sirve, mi respuesta???

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent gracias, la estoy revisando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No soy experto en JavaScript; y supongo que hay algún método mas básico o bonito; pero en teoría lo que buscas hacer es agregarle una propiedad con un array de objetos a la objeto datos.

Yo implementaría lo siguiente, dos `forEach` y una validación y asignación de valores a la propiedad:

```js
let json_str1 = JSON.parse(' [{"idAgen":36,"asesor":"ARCANGEL","idRegion":3,"region":"U","idZona":3,"zona":"ARIO","campos":291},{"idAgen":67,"asesor":"MIGUEL","idRegion":3,"region":"U","idZona":3,"zona":"ARIO","campos":888},{"idAgen":90,"asesor":"JOSE","idRegion":3,"region":"U","idZona":3,"zona":"ARIO","campos":291}]');

//console.log(json_str1);

let json_str2 = JSON.parse('[{"idAgen":36,"pronostico":410693},{"idAgen":36,"pronostico":8347},{"idAgen":67,"pronostico":9877},{"idAgen":67,"pronostico":9000},{"idAgen":67,"pronostico":5363},{"idAgen":90,"pronostico":896}]');

//console.log(json_str2);

json_str1.forEach((currentValue, key, data)=>{

  let tempObject=[];
  
  json_str2.forEach((currentValue2, key2, data2)=>{
  
    if(data[key].idAgen == data2[key2].idAgen){
      let value = data2[key2].pronostico;
      let object = {"pronostico":value};
      tempObject.push(object);
    }
    
  });
  
  if(tempObject.length>0){
    json_str1[key].pronostico=tempObject;
  }
  
});

console.log(json_str1);
```

documentacion sobre [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

**Otro método tambien que se puede emplear es con:** [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) y ciclos `for`

```js
let json_str1 = JSON.parse(' [{"idAgen":36,"asesor":"ARCANGEL","idRegion":3,"region":"U","idZona":3,"zona":"ARIO","campos":291},{"idAgen":67,"asesor":"MIGUEL","idRegion":3,"region":"U","idZona":3,"zona":"ARIO","campos":888},{"idAgen":90,"asesor":"JOSE","idRegion":3,"region":"U","idZona":3,"zona":"ARIO","campos":291}]');

//console.log(json_str1);

let json_str2 = JSON.parse('[{"idAgen":36,"pronostico":410693},{"idAgen":36,"pronostico":8347},{"idAgen":67,"pronostico":9877},{"idAgen":67,"pronostico":9000},{"idAgen":67,"pronostico":5363},{"idAgen":90,"pronostico":896}]');

for (const [key, data] of Object.entries(json_str1)) {
  let tempObject=[];
  for (const [key2, data2] of Object.entries(json_str2)) {
   
    if(data.idAgen == data2.idAgen){
      let value = data2.pronostico;
      let object = {"pronostico":value};
      tempObject.push(object);
    }
  }
  if(tempObject.length>0){
    json_str1[key].pronostico=tempObject;
  }
}

console.log(json_str1);
```